# Upgrade React Native 0.61.5: Android stuck on splash screen

Tags: java, android, reactjs, facebook, react-native

I upgraded React Native to 0.61.5, the iOS and Android parts compile successfully. The iOS app launch also successfully but not the Android app.

The Android app launch and stuck on splash screen with no error so I activated logs `adb logcat` and I found an error about Flipper:

`System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper`

After 2 day of try I have no idea how to resolve this issue. I have follow all migration procedure for React Native 0.6+ and all packages. This is where I am:

package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
        "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
        "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
        "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.1.0",
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.3",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.6.1",
        "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^6.1.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.1.0",
        "bugsnag-react-native": "^2.23.2",
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-native": "0.61.5",
        "react-native-config": "^0.11.7",
        "react-native-dark-mode": "^0.2.1",
        "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
        "react-native-device-info": "^5.3.1",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
        "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
        "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.1",
        "react-native-picker-select": "^6.3.3",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.17",
        "react-native-svg": "^9.13.3",
        "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
        "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.15",
        "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.3",
        "@types/jest": "^24.0.12",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.5",
        "@types/react": "^16.8.16",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.60.23",
        "@types/react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.0",
        "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.4",
        "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.8",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.8.1",
        "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "@types/sinon": "^7.0.2",
        "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
        "jest": "^24.8.0",
        "jest-fetch-mock": "^2.0.1",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
        "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0",
        "sinon": "^7.2.2",
        "snapshot-diff": "^0.4.1",
        "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
        "tslint": "^5.17.0",
        "typescript": "^3.7.3"
    },
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy {
       force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.0"
     }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into "libs"
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.dedge.centralinventory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactFragmentActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.dedge.centralinventory;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
            List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
            // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
            // packages.add();
            return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return "index";
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
        initializeFlipper(this); // Remove this line if you don't want Flipper enabled
    }

    /**
     * Loads Flipper in React Native templates.
     *
     * @param context
     */
    private static void initializeFlipper(Context context) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            try {
                /*
                 * We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper, since
                 * Flipper library is not available in release mode
                 */
                Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper");
                aClass.getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class).invoke(null, context);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to remove this line `initializeFlipper(this);` but it did not change anything.

**RESOLVED**

Finally I resolved my issue. `initializeFlipper(this);` was the first part of my problem. It's not compatible with the latest version of React Native (0.61.x). So I removed this line.

Next to that I had deleted `react-native-splash-screens` for upgrading React Native and I forgot to remove the override of `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` from `MainActivity.java` which stuck the app on splash screen.